# Problema para cambiar el nombre de todas las columnas de un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Dispongo un DataFrame en el que las etiquetas de columnas son las claves del diccionario

```
ticker_names = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50"}
```

Deseo sustituir estas etiquetas de columna, por los correspondientes valores en el diccionario. Para ello hago.

```
nombres_abreviados = ticker_names.values
yf_index_df.columns = nombres_abreviados 
yf_index_df
```

Al ejecutarlo me devuelve.

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 12
10 yf_index_df.head(3)
11 nombres_abreviados = ticker_names.values
---> 12 yf_index_df.columns = nombres_abreviados
14 yf_index_df

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5915, in NDFrame.**setattr**(self, name, value)
5913 try:
5914     object.**getattribute**(self, name)
-> 5915     return object.**setattr**(self, name, value)
5916 except AttributeError:
5917     pass

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx:69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.**set**()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:822, in NDFrame._set_axis(self, axis, labels)
821 def _set_axis(self, axis: int, labels: AnyArrayLike | list) -> None:
--> 822     labels = ensure_index(labels)
823     self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
824     self._clear_item_cache()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:7376, in ensure_index(index_like, copy)
7374         return Index._with_infer(index_like, copy=copy, tupleize_cols=False)
7375 else:
-> 7376     return Index._with_infer(index_like, copy=copy)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:717, in Index._with_infer(cls, *args, **kwargs)
715 with warnings.catch_warnings():
716     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", ".*the Index constructor", FutureWarning)
--> 717     result = cls(*args, **kwargs)
719 if result.dtype == _dtype_obj and not result._is_multi:
720     # error: Argument 1 to "maybe_convert_objects" has incompatible type
721     # "Union[ExtensionArray, ndarray[Any, Any]]"; expected
722     # "ndarray[Any, Any]"
723     values = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result._values)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:566, in Index.**new**(cls, data, dtype, copy, name, tupleize_cols, **kwargs)
561         return MultiIndex.from_tuples(
562             data, names=name or kwargs.get("names")
563         )
564 # other iterable of some kind
--> 566 subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=_dtype_obj)
567 if dtype is None:
568     # with e.g. a list [1, 2, 3] casting to numeric is *not* deprecated
569     subarr = _maybe_cast_data_without_dtype(
570         subarr, cast_numeric_deprecated=False
571     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py:238, in asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
235 def asarray_tuplesafe(values: Iterable, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> ArrayLike:
237     if not (isinstance(values, (list, tuple)) or hasattr(values, "**array**")):
--> 238         values = list(values)
239     elif isinstance(values, ABCIndex):
240         return values._values

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

¿Cuál puede ser la causa del error?. Agradeceré sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu DataFrame lleva por nombre `yf_index_df`, basta con:

```
yf_index_df.rename(columns=ticker_names, inplace=True)
```

Si no deseas utilizar el parámetro `inplace`, puedes hacer la reasignación:

```
yf_index_df = yf_index_df.rename(columns=ticker_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado iterando sobre el diccionario de la siguiente manera.

```
for key, value in ticker_names.items():
    yf_index_df = yf_index_df.rename(columns={key:value})
```